# Trying to get first item in object list

Tags: javascript, loops, dom

When I use this code it returns "4. numbers". How can I get the first item which is "1. strings" ?

```
const qOption1 = document.querySelector('.questionsOption1')
const questions = [{
questionText: "Commonly used data types DO NOT include:",
options: ["1. strings", "2. booleans", "3. alerts", "4. numbers"],
answer: "3. alerts",
}
for (let op of questions[0].options) {
  qOption1.innerHTML = op;
}
```

Comment: `questions[0].options[0]` will give you `1. strings`. What's the problem exactly? Do you want to display all the question options as radio buttons for all the questions?

Comment: I think you do have an error in your example code. constant questions starts with a `[`, indicating an array. And then holds an object `{}`, but you never close the array `]`

Answer (score 0):

`4. numbers` is the value of the last data array

```js
const qOption1 = document.querySelector('.questionsOption1')
const questions = [{
questionText: "Commonly used data types DO NOT include:",
options: ["1. strings", "2. booleans", "3. alerts", "4. numbers"],
answer: "3. alerts",
}]
let i = 0
for (let op of questions[0].options) {
  console.log(op,'array from', i++)
  qOption1.innerHTML += op+"<br/>";
}
```

```html
<div class="questionsOption1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit unclear, however I will try and give some answers.

Right now you are getting all the options, in a loop, and each iteration of the loop is overwriting the questionsOption1-element. Giving you the last item, once loop is done.

**Get first item in options array:**

If you simply want the first element from the `options` array of the first object in the `questions` array and set it to the `questionsOption1`-element it is very simple:

```
const qOption1 = document.querySelector('.questionsOption1')

const questions = [{
  questionText: "Commonly used data types DO NOT include:",
  options: ["1. strings", "2. booleans", "3. alerts", "4. numbers"],
  answer: "3. alerts",
}];

qOption1.innerHTML = questions[0].options[0];
```

As you can see, no loops needed.

You can also remove the first item from the array:

```
const firstOption = questions[0].options.shift();
```

**Get all option from first question:**

If you however want all the options for the first question then you would need to loop.

```
const qOptions = document.querySelector('.questionsOptions');

const questions = [{
    questionText: "Commonly used data types DO NOT include:",
    options: ["1. strings", "2. booleans", "3. alerts", "4. numbers"],
    answer: "3. alerts",
    }];

questions[0].options.forEach((option) => {
  qOptions.innerHTML = qOptions.innerHTML + `<span>${option}</span>`;
});
```

*Note: Changed elements class from `questionsOption1` to `questionsOptions`.*

**Get all questions and all options:**

```
const qElements = document.querySelector('.questions');

const questions = [{
    questionText: "Commonly used data types DO NOT include:",
    options: ["1. strings", "2. booleans", "3. alerts", "4. numbers"],
    answer: "3. alerts",
    },
    {
    questionText: "Another question:",
    options: ["1. A", "2. B", "3. C", "4. D"],
    answer: "3. C",
    }];

questions.forEach((question, index) => {
  qElements.innerHTML = qElements.innerHTML + `<div>Question ${index+1}</div>`;
  question.options.forEach((option) => {
     qElements.innerHTML = qElements.innerHTML + `<span>${option}</span>`;
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you so much. the first option is what I was looking for. all the options given will be helpful as well though.